# react-router - run nested onEnter functions simultaneously

Tags: react-router

I'm using react-router 1.0.3. Say I define these routes

```
<Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={appOnEnter}>
  <Route path="test" component={Test} onEnter={testOnEnter} />
</Route>
```

Both `appOnEnter` and `testOnEnter` are asynchronous functions. By default `testOnEnter` waits for `appOnEnter` to finish and call the `callback` to run, but I want those 2 `onEnter` functions to run simultaneously, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work with the react-router 1.0.3. I checked the source-code of it and don't see a way to call both hooks at the same time.

Here is a reference to the onEnter-Hook handling, if you might want to take a deeper look into it: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/modules/TransitionUtils.js

Maybe you can find a way to trick the system...

But I also would not recommend doing it. I don't have an idea of what you want to achieve but I think you should find a different approach, using other life-cycle hooks that react provides.